# Is GPU and SIMD likely to be implemented in .NET / Java VMs?

Tags: scala, f#, clojure, jvm, clr

For some time now, mainstream compute hardware has sported SIMD instructions (MMX, SSE, 3D-Now, etc) and more recently we're seeing AMD bringing 480-stream GPUs into the same die as the CPU.

Functional languages like F#, Scala and Clojure are also gaining traction, with one common attraction being how much easier concurrent programming is in these languages.

Are there any plans for the Java VM or .NET CLR to start providing access to parallel compute hardware resources, so that functional languages can mature to leverage the hardware?

It *seems* as though the VMs are currently the bottleneck against high performance computing, with SIMD and GPU access being delegated the 3rd party libraries and post-compilers (tidepowered.net, OpenTK, ScalaCL, Brahma, etc, etc.)

Does anyone know of any plans / roadmaps on the part of Microsoft / Oracle / Open-Source Community to being their VMs up-to-date with the new hardware and programming paradigms?

Is there a good reason why vendors are being so sluggish on the uptake?

Edit:

To Address feedback so far, it's true that GPU programming is complex and, done wrong, worsens performance. But it's well known that parallelism is the future of computing - so the crux of this question is that it doesn't help for hardware and programming languages to embrace a parallel paradigm if the runtimes sitting between the applications and the hardware don't support it... why aren't we seeing this on the VM vendor's radars / roadmaps?

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://code.google.com/p/scalacl/

Comment: No offense Mark, but have you done much GPU programming? Many things that are transparent normally, aren't there. There is local memory, shared memory, global memory, texture memory, low level thread synchronization that you can only get around by seriously restricting what you can do, and as far as I know NONE of that can be figured out automatically. They could do SIMD though, and IMO they should. The x64 JIT compiler already uses scalar SSE, I'm pretty sure they could *at least* special-case some common patterns such as Complex math.

Comment: +1 Harold - your right - there is much to consider when using a GPU, but the point is that there are still compute use cases for the GPU where simple parallel math (without synchronization) is useful. With AMD's fusion APUs, the problems of shared memory, etc, could (and should?) be handled by the VM.

Comment: @Mark: There are many academic projects doing this but the results have not been compelling enough for paying customers to want this from vendors so the vendors are not rushing.

Comment: Amazing question! Haskell should surely be all over this like a rash!

Answer (score 5):

you means JavaCL and ScalaCL? they both try to migrate CUDA/GPU programming to javavm

Comment: Scala also has parallel collection classes now

Comment: @Darren - yeah, but these projects *wrap* OpenCL, which still leaves much burden on the developer, when a JIT *could* pragmatically inspect the byte-code and determine that SIMD/GPU parallelism would result in a performance gain?

Comment: @Mark : While JavaCL does wrap OpenCL, ScalaCL completely hides OpenCL away from the programmer : instead of inspecting the byte-code (the way Aparapi does), it inspects the Scala AST during compilation, which provides much more useful information (and is much easier to do), and converts Scala code straight into OpenCL code. The burden goes away ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The mono runtime includes support for some SIMD instructions already - see http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3aMono.Simd

For Microsoft's implementation of the CLR you can use XNA which allows you to run shaders etc. or the accelerator library https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/accelerator/ which provides an interface to running GPGPU calculations

Comment: Yeah, and that's kinda what seems wrong (to me at least) - why should programmers be forced to use special libraries and acquire special skills to leverage basic SIMD and GPU compute resources? With a functional language, it should be possible for the compiler to determine which areas of execution can be safely handed over to a GPU, and then leave hints for the VM to do exactly that. This is what TidePowered.net attempts to emulate, by sitting between the compiler and the CLR runtime. Just seems like the whole thing would be a lot neater if the VM vendors implemented it, no?

Comment: `With a functional language, it should be possible for the compiler to determine which areas of execution can be safely handed over to a GPU` I guess that has a chance only in a Pure functional language like Haskell and not in impure languages like F# and Scala.

Comment: The VM automatically using the GPU is something I don't think will happen, for a few reasons.  1. transferring data back and forth to the GPU is slow. 2. no int/bool support on GPU 3. The need for groups of threads to all branch in the same way.  Using SIMD is more likely, but you run in to problems were SIMD instructions may not be faster for small data - see http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-git-gc-Speed-it-up-by-18-via-faster-hash-comparisons-td6311454.html for a real example were shifting off SIMD made git gc 20% faster.  I think alignment problems may also show up

Comment: @jpalmer - your right. Question is... just as functional languages infer types from usage, couldn't they also infer optimal layout from parallel usage scenarios?

Comment: @JohnPalmer A JIT could try to optimize to the GPU and see if it is faster. It could even run the GPU and CPU in parallell a few times (so as to lose no performance in either case, assuming no one else is using the resources :) and decide.

Comment: @Gurgeh - now you are just starting to run into the halting problem for general programs

Answer (score 3):

Java  has been making strong headway in the parallelism arena for some time, first with the java.util.concurrent package and now with  the fork/join framework. Hopefully, in the future, languages like Clojure and Scala will provide great high level abstractions to leverage fork-join.

GPGPU programming offers significant performance gains only for very specialized problems. .Net and Java are general purpose programming languages. Plus, who wants to do CUDA-style programming in a language like Java?

Comment: +1 for "who wants to do CUDA-style programming in a language like Java" - hence posting this question. I *don't* want to do CUDA style programming... I want the VM to figure out where SIMD/GPU optmizations are possible, and to re-shuffle private types / memory layout and instructions accordingly. While it's not trivial, it must be possible, right?

Answer (score 0):

Zach Tellman's [Penumbra](https://github.com/ztellman/penumbra) framework enables GPU programming in Clojure (both for graphics and general purpose programming).

It's somewhat experimental but I think the theoretical motivation is very sound:

- Harness the GPU / specialised SIMD instructions for the serious number crunching on large data sets
- Use a very high level langauge that is strong at metaprogramming / DSL definition (e.g. Clojure) to orchestrate the operations at the overall level and generate the appropriate lower-level code where needed (e.g. with generous use of macro expansions)